# Can we start hosting community chat discussions

Tags: discussion, chat

I see several other boards that host community discussions and I wanted to know can we start doing this?  Are we allowed to do this in beta?  What could be some topics to host?  Can we do this on a certain day at a certain time?

I thought we could possibly allow:

- a critique and allow some to get input on a design.
- Discussion of medium used for a design.
- Ideas on how to best choose a color palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see several other boards that host community discussions and I
>   wanted to know can we start doing this?

The chatroom is open to everybody for a reason. Any *user* (>=20 rep) can go ahead can initiate such an event and organize it. Any *room owner* can create it, however, its best if the event is created by a Moderator. The difference being that events created by Moderators get some automated publicity by appearing on the Community Bulletin an hour before the event starts.

> Are we allowed to do this in beta?

Yes.

> What could be some topics to host?

If chat is not very active, then general discussions would be a good way to kick off things. Alternatively, there could be themed or targeted discussions too.

> Can we do this on a certain day at a certain time?

Yes. Time and date have to be decided before the event is/can-be created.